# How to remove a python turtle

Tags: python, python-turtle

I am making a game in python turtle. I have a function which spawns an extra turtle but I also want it to disappear after some time, but I can find a way to fully delete it.
i have tried blanking the variable and using del but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python turtles are global entities that are never reclaimed while the turtle screen is active.  To disable a turtle, simply use `hideturtle()`.  My recommendation, if you're creating turtles dynamically, is to add disabled (hidden) turtles to a list of turtles to reuse when you need one -- you can `reset()` a turtle.  Only create a new turtle if that list is empty.